# Get bearer token using delegated authentication

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-sdks

With reference to this article [Authorization Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#authorization-request).
If my application user is already logged in, how can I request to get my profile using SDK or this API reference: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/`

SDK code I wrote:

```
public async Task<string> GetFullNameAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _client.Me
                .Request()
                .Select(data => data.DisplayName)
                .GetAsync();
            return user.DisplayName;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "404 Not Found";
        }
    }
```

For that, how can I get a bearer token string using delegated authentication for Web Application and single tenant in .NET Core as mentioned in the above article?

Comment: Did you try step 3?  Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?  I think the 404 error is due to using HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: I am getting errors because I tried application authorization instead of delegated authorization which is configured in my azure application. I just don't know how can I convert that article into an actual .NET Core code.

Comment: Sample isn't using Windows Authentication. It is using 
 OAuth 2 : see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

Comment: Yes, users are getting login in the web app using OAuth2.0 Azure AD

Comment: The OAuth2 is in the URL and is a parameter after the question mark in the URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111.  So all you have to do is modify the URL

Comment: But the code I need is in the response URL, when I make the request, it returns the sign in page, then check if user is already login so it redirects in actual, but in HTTP request it won't redirect.

Comment: An HTTP message has three parts 1) URL : contains a path and after the question mark contains parameters separated by ampersand(s) 2) HTTP Headers (key followed by colon and value 3) Body.   The link Authorize Request (at top of posting) you have to look closely at the examples to see the three parts. If you look at section 5 of the link it is clear what is the URL and Headers but no clear about the parameters because there is no question mark.  The section starting with client_id should be in the URL after a question mark.  Should look similar to example in section 2.

Answer (score 0):

***To get bearer token using delegated authentication, please check the below if helpful:***

- Make use of **Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph** nuget package to implement Graph API from an ASP. NET Core web application.
- The application authentication and the authorization are setup in the Startup class.
- For **delegated** user access token make use of **AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication** method as below sample code:

```js
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{  
services.AddHttpClient();  
services.AddScoped<GraphApiClientDirect>();  
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration)  
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()  
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();  
services.AddControllers(options =>  
{  
var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()  
.RequireAuthenticatedUser()  
.Build();  
options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));  
});  
}
```

- Use **GetAccessTokenForUserAsync** method, to get new delegated access token for required scopes.
- The ***Graph API client service*** can then be used in the API which is protected using the **Microsoft.Identity .Web** packages.

```cs
[Authorize]  
[ApiController]  
[Route("[controller]")]  
public class GraphCallsController : ControllerBase  
{  
private readonly GraphApiClientDirect _graphApiClientDirect;  
  
public GraphCallsController(GraphApiClientDirect graphApiClientDirect)  
{  
_graphApiClientDirect = graphApiClientDirect;  
}  
[HttpGet]  
public async Task<string> Get()  
{  
var user = await _graphApiClientDirect.GetGraphApiUser()  
.ConfigureAwait(false);  
return user.DisplayName;  
}  
}
```

- The correct initialization must be used while using Graph API client in ASP.NET Core applications for **delegated** access user access tokens.
- Use the **`IHttpClientFactory`** to create the HttpClient instance to create instance.
- Use **`ITokenAcquisition`** and the IHttpClientFactory interfaces to create the GraphApiClient requests for different scopes.

Please find below **references** to know more in detail:

[Using Microsoft Graph API in ASP.NET Core | Software Engineering (damienbod.com)](https://damienbod.com/2020/11/20/using-microsoft-graph-api-in-asp-net-core/)

[Secure a .NET Core API using Bearer Authentication - Dotnet Playbook](https://dotnetplaybook.com/secure-a-net-core-api-using-bearer-authentication/)